# How to execute a text extracted through grep and sed in bash

Tags: bash, sed, grep

I am trying to execute a command based on extracting it from README file. 
I was able to extract it using grep and sed:

```
cat README.md |  grep -i "docker build" | grep -vi "dockerfile.debug" |  sed 's/.*\(d[a-z]\).*/\1/'
```

This script would give a result something like 'docker build .'
I want to execute that command.

But I am not sure how to execute the extracted text. I thought 'exec' would work but I couldn't apply it. Please help me find a way to execute the text extracted through the above script.

Comment: Append `| bash`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set your command in

```
$(CommandToExecute)
```

or back-ticks

```
`CommandToExecute`
```

As Example:

```
$(cat README.md |  grep -i "docker build" | grep -vi "dockerfile.debug" |  sed 's/.*\(d[a-z]\).*/\1/'
);
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
$(grep -i "docker build" README.md | grep -vi "dockerfile.debug" |  sed 's/.*\(d[a-z]\).*/\1/')
```